# How to use Context.io in .NET for verifying emails in inbox

Tags: c#, oauth, google-oauth, contextio

Can someone help me with samples where there is use of **context.io** to get mail content using c# ? I am trying to get mails for **gmail**.

Comment: try using 3rd party APIs. example POP3, MIME

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.